# how can i implement "People also search for" just like google

Tags: php, apache, search, solr

Hi, I was wondering what is the way to implement "People also search for"; when you do a search for something, you could show something on the side saying people who searched for this also. You can see this in Google Play.

Do I need Apache solr or something?

Comment: what you need i a more bit effort on research.. try google..

Comment: What have you tried so far? What plans for implementation do you have in mind?

Comment: You do realize that Google has had thousands of engineers working on their search functionality for many years. If you want to implement something "just like Google" you are going to have a very long way to go and will have to learn a lot about algorithms, machine learning, etc.  You should start out with a more humble goal. Perhaps start learning with some more off-the-shelf tools (like Solr), find out a bit about how they work. Figure out how you may be able to leverage such tools to give you the sort of functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can Implement it in Apache Solr is:-

1. Create Solr Document with User Id and Searches Performed by the Users
2. You would have the Collection with all your users and the Searches Performed.
3. You can then easily search or filter on Solr for the search query, which would give you all the users who searched for the same search query.
4. In Addition just facet on the search query field and you would have a list of all the other search queries performed by these users in order or the frequency.

You can probably implement it via other methods as well.